# Can I implement a property setter in such a way that it calls another method generically to perform the set?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider the below setters:

```
- (void)setWinterStatus:(NSString *)status
{
    NSLog(@"Variable update called");
    if (_status != status)
    {
        [_status release];
        _status = [status retain];
        NSLog(@"Variable actually updated");
    }
}

- (void)setCharacterState:(EnumCharacterState)state
{
    NSLog(@"Variable update called");
    if (_state != state)
    {
        _state = state;
        NSLog(@"Variable actually updated");
    }
}
```

Notice the methods are similar - it logs a generic message, checks if it's actually changing, effects the change, and logs if it does so. If I had enough such methods, I might want to write a wrapper, so that I could simply write:

```
- (void)setCharacterState:(EnumCharacterState)state
{
    [setValue:@(state) forSelector:@selector(state)];
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is possible. I can't use KVO as it seems the KVO code added by default actually call's the setter, so doing so results in endless recursion. I don't know how to get the *instance* variable from `@selector(state)`, nor check whether it needs `release/retain`. Any way to do this?

One note: the object type's base class has to remain `NSObject`; I can't use `NSManagedObject` as a base and handle my own KVO.

Edit:

So there apparently is a way using the runtime c functions (see accepted answer); seems like it could take some time to get right, but I found another solution in the interim. I register myself an an observer for all the methods I want to 'wrap', observing `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`, `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld`, and `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior`. Then in the prior handler, I `NSLog(@"Variable update called")`, and in the update handler, I `NSLog(@"Variable actually updated")`. This seems to be working out well :)

Comment: Why would you implement such custom setters if the implementation is what you are showing here? They're not doing anything different from auto-synthesised properties accessors.

Comment: This is just a minimal example describing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Yes, but don't.

**Long Answer**:

Assuming you want to do this for educational reasons (rather than just have the compiler create the setter for you, the default in recent compilers) it is possible, but it is non-trivial.

You've noticed one difference - whether you need to retain/release (assuming MRC) - but there are more. For example, consider the simple line:

```
_state = state;
```

What does it do? Copy a byte? Two bytes? Eight bytes? The code might *look* the same in different setters but it compiles to different machine code.

And then there are copy and weak attributes on properties to consider...

*Still considering doing this?*

You'll need to be comfortable with what `void **` means, copying data of variable length via pointers, etc. Then take a look at `object_setInstanceVariable`, `property_getAttributes` etc. - these are all C functions, you'll find them in [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html).

From that you'll find you need to know about [type encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100) (which will help you with how many bytes to copy around), and more...

Have fun!

HTH

Comment: I don't suppose you know how `NSManagedObject` works with `@dynamic`? Does it create new instance methods when you load the mom perhaps, or use something similar to Message Forwarding?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - That's a different question ;) Offhand, no.

Comment: I was thinking whatever NSMangedObject does is likely to be the best answer to this question also.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - I can see your line of thinking, but the public Objective-C runtime functions are probably the best place to start for user code.

Comment: This was my thought as well - I could implement 'SetPrimitiveForKey' to handle my own support for KVO, and then add whatever I want before/after that. As it turns out, I found a solution I like even better, which I will add to my original post. I will mark this as the answer as it does point to an interesting implementation option, even though it doesn't *quite* give a full answer.

Comment: @Rollie you should post your own answer and mark it as accepted if it's different from this one. Then just upvote CRD's answer for being helpful.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I would agree with that, except that my 'answer' is more of a workaround by approaching the problem differently. The solution CRD provided actually solves the question as I asked it.